# How to delay showing elements until slideToggle is completed?

Tags: jquery

This is my code.

```
$(".big").click(function() {
    var widget = $(this).parent();
    widget.children('.layer-dark').slideToggle(300).fadeTo(1, 0.97);
    widget.children('.loading, .hm_sm_btn').show();
});
```

Now how can I make the `.loading` and `.hm_sm_btn show()` get done after the previous action `slideToggle` is completed. right now, the items get instantly shown so I am looking for some simple and easy way to make a short delay and make them appear after `slideToggle()` is completed.

Hope my question is clear, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
widget.children('.layer-dark').slideToggle(300, function() {
    widget.children('.loading, .hm_sm_btn').show();
}).fadeTo(1, 0.97);
```

Use the callback.

The [`.slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) documentation clearly shows you can pass in a callback to do further computation when the slideToggle action finishes.

You should spend more time reading the documentation. It's good.

Answer (score 0):

You may add a callback function for the `slideToggle` function (see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)):

```
$(".big").click(function() {
    var widget = $(this).parent();
    widget.children('.layer-dark')
          .slideToggle(300, function() { widget.children('.loading, .hm_sm_btn').show() })
          .fadeTo(1, 0.97);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try the callback way.

`$(".big").click(function() {
    var widget = $(this).parent();
    widget.children('.layer-dark').slideToggle(300, function(){
       widget.children('.loading, .hm_sm_btn').show();
    }).fadeTo(1, 0.97);
});`